# Laravel Artisan Commands - No Colors In CMD Terminal

Tags: laravel, windows, terminal, colors, ansi-escape

I'm using windows 10, Laravel 5.2 and php artisan 
commands are displaying ansi color code characters
instead of the color itself.  Below is an example of 
`php artisan --version`:

```
?[32mLaravel Framework?[39m version ?[33m5.2.45?[39m
```

I don't see this problem with composer or git commands in terminal.

Is there a fix other than installing a 3rd party terminal (eg: conemu) ?

Comment: The built-in terminal is the console host, not the CMD *shell*. By default the console is configured without virtual terminal support. The CMD shell enables it for itself only, and restores the initial setting when it runs an external program. So change the default setting. In "HKCU\Console", create a DWORD named "VirtualTerminalLevel" with the value 1.

Comment: awesome, that worked, thank you very much !!